# How to use OpenSSL to encrypt/decrypt files?

Tags: encryption, openssl

I want to encrypt and decrypt one file using one password.

How can I use OpenSSL to do that?

Comment: You should derive a Key and IV from the password using `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC`. You should use the `EVP_*` functions to encrypt and decrypt. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. In fact, you should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: Don't understand from your question why you want OpenSSL. A comment below shows GPG is better - also because of security. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31552829/952234 I vote down.

Comment: You may like to look at "keepout" so as to save all the encryption options used with the encrypted file...  This is especially important now that 'default' options of openssl enc has changed, and will likely change in the future.   Also sets a higher and randomised iteration count for the new -pbkdf2 option.    https://antofthy.gitlab.io/software/#keepout

Comment: I can not decrypt with none of these code, is there any to help me and decrypt my file? @matthias Braun

Answer (score 352, accepted):

> **Security Warning**: AES-256-CBC does not provide [authenticated encryption](https://tonyarcieri.com/all-the-crypto-code-youve-ever-written-is-probably-broken) and is vulnerable to [padding oracle attacks](https://robertheaton.com/2013/07/29/padding-oracle-attack). You should use something like [age](https://github.com/FiloSottile/age) instead.

Encrypt:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -pbkdf2 -in secrets.txt -out secrets.txt.enc
```

Decrypt:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -pbkdf2 -in secrets.txt.enc -out secrets.txt.new
```

[More details on the various flags](https://tombuntu.com/index.php/2007/12/12/simple-file-encryption-with-openssl/)

Comment: Answer is likely not optimal (as of this writing) depending on OP's use case. Specifically the parameters "-a" is likely not optimal and the answer does not explain its use. "-a" is typically used when the encrypted output is to be transmitted in ASCII/text form and has the effect of increasing output size compared binary form. The original poster does not specify output format and so I feel that at the very least this should be mentioned. See answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31552829/952234 which also includes a note on why you should use gpg instead of openssl for this task.

Comment: Do not use the above command since there is no key derivation. Read more here: [openssl weak key derivation](https://www.reddit.com/r/crypto/comments/4gu3df/weak_key_derivation_in_openssl/)

Comment: Should also specify a key, or mention where it comes from.  Is it strengthened?

Comment: *"This is the top answer to your question from google..."* - But he's on Stack Overflow, and he wants a C/C++ solution.

Comment: @jonasl according to the latest man page, it states:  “The default digest was changed from MD5 to SHA256 in Openssl 1.1.0.” Source: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/doc/man1/enc.pod

Comment: Adding to the comment from @Kebman, you can add `-md sha256` to your encode and decode command if you plan on using this file on another machine. That should cover you against OpenSSL version incompatibilities/differences

Comment: why don't you use asymmetric algorithm ? It's safer to not have the "secret" to encrypt and keep it for later at decrypt time :-)

Comment: -pbkdf2 is no longer a valid option on Mac M1.

Comment: Isn't this insecure? I mean anyone who can guess the encryption method can crack the code easily, right???

Answer (score 271):

### Using GPG (Better Alternative to OpenSSL)

Though you have specifically asked about OpenSSL (see **"Using OpenSSL"** below for OpenSSL solution) you might want to consider using GPG instead for the purpose of encryption based on this article [OpenSSL vs GPG for encrypting off-site backups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247821/openssl-vs-gpg-for-encrypting-off-site-backups)

To use GPG to do the same you would use the following commands:

**To Encrypt:**

```
gpg --output encrypted.data --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 un_encrypted.data
```

**To Decrypt:**

```
gpg --output un_encrypted.data --decrypt encrypted.data
```

*Note: You will be prompted for a password when encrypting or decrypt.* And use `--no-symkey-cache` flag for no cache.

---

### Using OpenSSL (Short Answer)

*You likely want to use `gpg` instead of `openssl` as mentioned above but to answer the question using `openssl`:*

**To Encrypt:**

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in un_encrypted.data -out encrypted.data
```

**To Decrypt:**

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in encrypted.data -out un_encrypted.data
```

*Note: You will be prompted for a password when encrypting or decrypt.*

---

### Using OpenSSL (Long Answer)

Your best source of information for `openssl enc` would probably be: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html

**Command line:**
`openssl enc` takes the following form:

```
openssl enc -ciphername [-in filename] [-out filename] [-pass arg]
[-e] [-d] [-a/-base64] [-A] [-k password] [-kfile filename] 
[-K key] [-iv IV] [-S salt] [-salt] [-nosalt] [-z] [-md] [-p] [-P] 
[-bufsize number] [-nopad] [-debug] [-none] [-engine id]
```

Explanation of most useful parameters with regards to your question:

```
-e
    Encrypt the input data: this is the default.

-d    
    Decrypt the input data.

-k <password>
    Only use this if you want to pass the password as an argument. 
    Usually you can leave this out and you will be prompted for a 
    password. The password is used to derive the actual key which 
    is used to encrypt your data. Using this parameter is typically
    not considered secure because your password appears in 
    plain-text on the command line and will likely be recorded in 
    bash history.

-kfile <filename>
    Read the password from the first line of <filename> instead of
    from the command line as above.

-a
    base64 process the data. This means that if encryption is taking 
    place the data is base64 encoded after encryption. If decryption 
    is set then the input data is base64 decoded before being 
    decrypted.
    You likely DON'T need to use this. This will likely increase the
    file size for non-text data. Only use this if you need to send 
    data in the form of text format via email etc.

-salt
    To use a salt (randomly generated) when encrypting. You always
    want to use a salt while encrypting. This parameter is actually
    redundant because a salt is used whether you use this or not 
    which is why it was not used in the "Short Answer" above!

-K key    
    The actual key to use: this must be represented as a string
    comprised only of hex digits. If only the key is specified, the
    IV must additionally be specified using the -iv option. When 
    both a key and a password are specified, the key given with the
    -K option will be used and the IV generated from the password 
    will be taken. It probably does not make much sense to specify 
    both key and password.

-iv IV
    The actual IV to use: this must be represented as a string 
    comprised only of hex digits. When only the key is specified 
    using the -K option, the IV must explicitly be defined. When a
    password is being specified using one of the other options, the 
    IV is generated from this password.

-md digest
    Use the specified digest to create the key from the passphrase.
    The default algorithm as of this writing is sha-256. But this 
    has changed over time. It was md5 in the past. So you might want
    to specify this parameter every time to alleviate problems when
    moving your encrypted data from one system to another or when
    updating openssl to a newer version.
```

Comment: Great comment about preferring GPG over OpenSSL.  I find it incredible that OpenSSL uses such a weak password derived hash for the key!

Comment: When trying to decrypt with gpg 2.1.15: `Note: '--output' is not considered an option`
How do you get the decrypted date into a file? Is it OK to do `... >> un_encrypted.data` ?

Comment: Be sure to use the "-md md5" option for compatibility with files that were encrypted on older openssl without the -md option specified, otherwise you will find that files won't decrypt on newer systems: https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/issues/378

Comment: Default values change between versions of openssl. 1.0.x uses a default of md5 for the -md option. Version 1.1.x uses sha256. If you decrypt and get a ":digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt" error. try specifying "-md md5" or "-md sha256".

Comment: "You will be prompted for a password when encrypting or decrypt." `gpg` is letting me decrypt a file without being prompted for a password. It looks like the password is stored for some period of time, which I don't want.

Comment: @user76284 This might address your issue: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395876/79875 . I think you have `gpg-agent` running

Comment: @moo It also seems that the option `--no-symkey-cache` disables caching when using gpg with `--symmetric`, even if the agent is running.

Comment: The placement of the `--no-symkey-cache` flag is important: `$ gpg --output encrypted.data --symmetric --no-symkey-cache --cipher-algo AES256 un_encrypted.data`. If tacked onto the end of the line you will receive `gpg: Note: '--no-symkey-cache' is not considered an option`. It was first added in version 2.2.7.

Answer (score 50):

**Encrypt:**

```
openssl enc -in infile.txt -out encrypted.dat -e -aes256 -k symmetrickey
```

**Decrypt:**

```
openssl enc -in encrypted.dat -out outfile.txt -d -aes256 -k symmetrickey
```

For details, see the [`openssl(1)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html) docs.

Comment: To use a plaintext password, replace `-k symmetrickey` with `-pass stdin` or `-pass 'pass:PASSWORD'`

Comment: Do not use the above command since there is no key derivation. Read more here: [openssl weak key derivation](https://www.reddit.com/r/crypto/comments/4gu3df/weak_key_derivation_in_openssl/)

Comment: Related to @jonasl's comment, note that `-k symmetrickey` is misleading.  The `-k` option is used for specifying a password, from which OpenSSL derives the symmetric key.  If you want to specify the symmetric key, you must use the `-K` option.

Comment: @Andrii Abramov I can not decrypt with none of these code, is there any to help me and decrypt my file?

Answer (score 29):

DO NOT USE OPENSSL DEFAULT KEY DERIVATION.

Currently the accepted answer makes use of it and it's no longer recommended and secure.

It is very feasible for an attacker to simply brute force the key.

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt

> PBKDF1 applies a hash function, which shall be MD2 [6], MD5 [19] or
>      SHA-1 [18], to derive keys. The length of the derived key is bounded
>      by the length of the hash function output, which is 16 octets for MD2
>      and MD5 and 20 octets for SHA-1. PBKDF1 is compatible with the key
>      derivation process in PKCS #5 v1.5. PBKDF1 is recommended only for compatibility with existing
>      applications since the keys it produces may not be large enough for
>      some applications.
>
> PBKDF2 applies a pseudorandom function (see Appendix B.1 for an
>      example) to derive keys. The length of the derived key is essentially
>      unbounded. (However, the maximum effective search space for the derived key may be limited by the structure of the underlying
>      pseudorandom function. See Appendix B.1 for further discussion.)
>      PBKDF2 is recommended for new applications.

Do this:

`openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -iter 20000 -in hello -out hello.enc -k meow`

`openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -iter 20000 -in hello.enc -out hello.out`

**Note**: Iterations in decryption have to be the same as iterations in encryption.

Iterations have to be a minimum of 10000.
Here is a good answer on the number of iterations: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/3993

Also... we've got enough people here recommending GPG. Read the damn question.

Comment: NOTE:  PBKDF2 is now part of the openssl enc (finally).
However the iteration count is extrememly low, and needs to be set to a much higher level.  If that count is randomised, then you also get a extra level of 'saltiness' to your encryption.

Comment: The linked article is great. It also hints that instead of picking high count, which increases computational resources linearly, one can simply use strong password with high entropy, causing computational complexity to grow exponentially. Every extra 10 bits of entropy is equivalent to multiplying iter count by 1000. E.g. if you have >28 random characters (from a set of 62) as a password you don't need to worry about the iteration count altogether.

Comment: It would be really beneficial if below those two statements, that you defined all the switches and commands used.

Comment: What is the -k? Its not in the man pages.

Comment: @AndrewS - fist line:  use `aes-256-cbc` as the "Cypher command", `-pbkdf2` is the "Password-Based Key Derivation Function, 2nd gen.", `-iter` is the number of iterations the key derivation function runs, `-in` input file, `-out` result of encryption/decryption, `-k` literally the password used.  The second command will prompt for the password, which is `meow` in this case.  For your sake, use a vastly longer passphrase than `meow` ;).  Note I usually use `-pass file:keyfile` and `keyfile` is usually a 64+ character file.  You'll need that to decrypt, so don't lose it!

Comment: for the record: `-iter 1000000` (1mil) takes about a second to decrypt on my machine

Answer (score 17):

As mentioned in the other answers, previous versions of openssl used a weak key derivation function to derive an AES encryption key from the password.  However, openssl v1.1.1 supports a stronger key derivation function, where the key is derived from the password using `pbkdf2` with a randomly generated salt, and multiple iterations of sha256 hashing (10,000 by default).

To encrypt a file:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -e -salt -pbkdf2 -iter 10000 -in plaintextfilename -out encryptedfilename
```

To decrypt a file:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -salt -pbkdf2 -iter 10000 -in encryptedfilename -out plaintextfilename
```

Note: An equivalent/compatible implementation in javascript (using the web crypto api) can be found at https://github.com/meixler/web-browser-based-file-encryption-decryption.

Comment: Which as these options keep changing, means you need to also keep a record of what options was used when creating each openssl encrypted file.  Especially as the iteration count should increase with time!
For one solution see as relatively simple wrapper around openssl enc...  "keepout"   https://antofthy.gitlab.io/software/#keepout    It can expand to include more openssl are time goes on.

Comment: You need to explain all of those switches, without that its just magic code with no understanding provided.

Comment: @AndrewS agreed - the openssl man page isn't nearly as nice as most others.  You need to _know_ that you have to look at `man enc` instead, for the options on using `openssl enc`.

Answer (score 8):

Update using a random generated public key.

**Encypt:**

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in {raw data} -out {encrypted data} -pass file:{random key}
```

**Decrypt:**

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in {ciphered data} -out {raw data}
```

Comment: would be better if that page is still online and it uses https

Answer (score 8):

**To Encrypt:**

```
$ openssl bf < arquivo.txt > arquivo.txt.bf
```

**To Decrypt:**

```
$ openssl bf -d < arquivo.txt.bf > arquivo.txt
```

bf === Blowfish in CBC mode

Comment: This doesn't work in openssl 3, was written.

Answer (score 3):

There is an open source program that I find online it uses openssl to encrypt and decrypt files. It does this with a single password. The great thing about this open source script is that it deletes the original unencrypted file by shredding the file. But the dangerous thing about is once the original unencrypted file is gone you have to make sure you remember your password otherwise they be no other way to decrypt your file.

Here the link it is on github

https://github.com/EgbieAnderson1/linux_file_encryptor/blob/master/file_encrypt.py

Comment: Things have changed when using openssl for file encryption, their are a lot more options, which needs need to be remembers so you can successfully decrypt encrypted files.  One solution to this is "keepout"  https://antofthy.gitlab.io/software/#keepout

Answer (score 2):

Note that the OpenSSL CLI uses a weak non-standard algorithm to convert the passphrase to a key, and installing GPG results in various files added to your home directory and a gpg-agent background process running. If you want maximum portability and control with existing tools, you can use PHP or Python to access the lower-level APIs and directly pass in a full AES Key and IV.

Example PHP invocation via Bash:

```
IV='c2FtcGxlLWFlcy1pdjEyMw=='
KEY='Twsn8eh2w2HbVCF5zKArlY+Mv5ZwVyaGlk5QkeoSlmc='
INPUT=123456789023456

ENCRYPTED=$(php -r "print(openssl_encrypt('$INPUT','aes-256-ctr',base64_decode('$KEY'),OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING,base64_decode('$IV')));")
echo '$ENCRYPTED='$ENCRYPTED
DECRYPTED=$(php -r "print(openssl_decrypt('$ENCRYPTED','aes-256-ctr',base64_decode('$KEY'),OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING,base64_decode('$IV')));")
echo '$DECRYPTED='$DECRYPTED
```

This outputs:

```
$ENCRYPTED=nzRi252dayEsGXZOTPXW
$DECRYPTED=123456789023456
```

You could also use PHP's `openssl_pbkdf2` function to convert a passphrase to a key securely.

Comment: Openssl CLI now implements and warns users that they should use PBKDF2 for password hashing.   However its default iteration count is very low, and needs to be much larger.