# Openssl aes encryption seems not to work for me

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes

I tried to use `aes-256-ebc` encryption with Openssl, but it seems my output is not what I expected. The key and test vectors I used are taken from http://www.inconteam.com/software-development/41-encryption/55-aes-test-vectors#aes-ecb-256

My input is the following:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-ecb -in in.bin -nosalt -out out.bin -kfile k.bin -nopad
```

For example, I'm using `6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172a` as test vector.

My out.bin is:

```
BD E8 25 14 C9 30 E8 86 CA B7 55 93 D7 B3 AB F1
```

instead of:

```
f3eed1bdb5d2a03c064b5a7e3db181f8
```

My question is if I'm using Openssl the wrong way or what could have caused this mistake?

Comment: This might be of interest to you: [How to use OpenSSL to encrypt/decrypt files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056135/how-to-use-openssl-to-encrypt-decrypt-files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh well, time to test my command line fu. Didn't know I still had any :)

```
echo "6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172a" | perl -pe 's/([0-9a-f]{2})/chr hex $1/gie' | openssl enc -e -aes-256-ecb -K `cat key.hex` | xxd -p
```

Comment: You can simply replace the echo and perl part by `-in in.bin` if `in.bin` contains the right bytes of course, but otherwise it would not be a challenge.

Comment: If you think my answer helped, please don't forget to accept the answer using the V mark on the left...