# Encrypt file with 256 bit AES key from s3cmd tool

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, s3cmd

I've got a bucket with some amount of unencrypted files, I need to encrypt them with 256 bit AES key. I've already written a java code to encrypt those files and it is working fine. What I am wondering is if the s3cmd tool provided also supports the encryption process, if it did it would save me a lot of time.
I've already generated a AES key if I could somehow use the s3cmd put command to recursively encrypt all the files it would be a great help. Anyone pleas.... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use server side encryption where S3 will encrypt the data for you as it stores it. It will do the decryption also on retrieval. All you need to do is supply the key.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/serv-side-encryption.html

This says it's available in s3cmd from 1.5.0-beta1 - the current version is 1.5.2 so it should be there but i can't find any examples on the net.

http://s3tools.org/kb/item9.htm

Comment: Actually I need a client side encryption since I already have my own key file

Comment: how does it make a difference, if the encryption level is the same, the key should be the same? either way, i don't think any S3 command is going to encrypt the files locally before upload. you probably just want to look at normal encryption tools (which would add .aes extensions?) and then sync the files normally.

Comment: in that case I guess I have no option than to use the java code i've created. Thanks anyway

Comment: no you use openssl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056135/how-to-use-openssl-to-encrypt-decrypt-files