# How to encrypt and decrypt a string/text in shell (linux environment)

Tags: linux

I have a string, which is actually password. I want to encrypt the string and want to store the encrypted result in a parameter file. Next during execution of a script that encrypted string will be picked up and in run time that will be decrypt. So I want to know how to encrypt and decrypt a string/text in linux environment?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056135/how-to-use-openssl-to-encrypt-decrypt-files ?

Comment: The only concern is it is asking for password during encription  and decryption which I don't want. Can we set it up this password less

Answer (score 43):

This isn't quite what was being asked for here but it shows a simple way to do this without a password prompt

Using:

```
openssl version
LibreSSL 2.8.3
```

## encode.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo $1 | openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:somepassword
```

## decode.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo $1 | openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -pass pass:somepassword
```

### make files executable

```
chmod +x encode.sh decode.sh
```

### encode example

```
./encode.sh "this is my test string"
# => U2FsdGVkX18fjSHGEzTXU08q+GG2I4xrV+GGtfDLg+T3vxpllUc/IHnRWLgoUl9q
```

### decode example

```
./decode.sh U2FsdGVkX18fjSHGEzTXU08q+GG2I4xrV+GGtfDLg+T3vxpllUc/IHnRWLgoUl9q
# => this is my test string
```

Comment: Might be a good to add the `-pbkdf2` flag to each, too

Comment: Indeed the proposed commands now show *** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.

Comment: Those commands should use `echo -n "$1"`, otherwise `echo`'s trailing '\n' will be part of the encrypted string. If this string is used from somewhere else (e.g. a UI), where you cannot enter the newline explicitly, de-/encryption will fail.

Comment: Just a side note - when you use OpenSSL to encrypt you will need to use OpenSSL to decrypt as well. The same regarding OpenSSL on OSX (LibreSSL).

Answer (score 8):

openssl can do it better.

encode:

```
$ secret=$(echo "this is a secret." | openssl enc -e -des3 -base64 -pass pass:mypasswd -pbkdf2)
```

decode:

```
$ echo "${secret}" | openssl enc -d -des3 -base64 -pass pass:mypasswd -pbkdf2
```

tips:

- you can remove arg -pass and intput password according to the prompt.

Comment: This answer is great but unfortunately openssl doesn't support url safe base64 encoding so this won't work for my use case.  A proposal was put forward but as of this writing it isn't being worked on.

Answer (score 1):

## using gpg

**this is file based but can use stdin**

This method requires [gpg keys](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x56.html) availible.

### encrypt.sh

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input_file="${1? must provide an input file}"
recipient="${RECIPIENT? must provide recipient email}"
output_file="${input_file}.gpg"

gpg \
  --quiet \
  --output "${output_file}" \
  --encrypt \
  --sign \
  --armor \
  --recipient "${recipient}" \
  "${input_file}" \
  ;
```

### decrypt.sh

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input_file="${1? must provide an input file}"
output_file=${input_file%.gpg}

gpg \
  --output "${output_file}" \
  --decrypt "${input_file}" \
  ;
```

```bash
chmod +x encrypt.sh decrypt.sh
```

- Create a file to test with

```yaml
# test.yml
secret: "Hello World"
pin: 3918
```

### encrypt

**must have billy@proton.me public key***

```bash
RECIPIENT=billy@proton.me ./encrypt.sh test.yml
```

This creates `test.yml.gpg`

### decrypt

**must have billy@proton.me secret key***

```bash
./decrypt.sh test.yml.gpg
```