# How to encrypt a file with AES using OpenSSL?

Tags: encryption, openssl

I am new to shell script. In my project there is a requirement to keep all the sensitive data in encrypted format. For to achieve this I need to openssl in command line tool. I tried the following command 
*openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in secrets.txt -out secrets.txt.enc* 
It is not asking me to enter password. And it is not showing anything. Please help me to solve this problem.
[Clik here to see the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTdix.png)

Comment: This question might be better phrased as "How to encrypt a file with AES using OpenSLL"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use OpenSSL to encrypt/decrypt files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056135/how-to-use-openssl-to-encrypt-decrypt-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with `openssl` not providing any output.  Executed the same using `winpty` and it worked as expected:

```
$ winpty openssl enc -salt -aes-256-cbc -in file -out file.enc
enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
Verifying - enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:

$ git --version
git version 2.14.1.windows.1
```

Comment: I had the same issue and this worked for me too, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the question is indeed, "How do I encrypt a file with AES" then I think this line might work, found from either [here](https://superuser.com/a/370412/247069), or [here](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2017/01/17/tutorial-aes-encryption-and-decryption-with-openssl/).

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in secrets.txt -out secrets.txt.enc
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tom for the answer. I am working in windows environment. I executed above command in git bash, didn't get any output.