# how to create a file in shell script with specific password

Tags: shell, unix

i am looking for a way to create a password protected file in Shell with same password instead of random password since we need to ftp the file to 3rd party hence we dont need the password to be changed every time , Below is my sample code snipet ,

```
echo "STORE,CUSTOMER,START TIME,END TIME" > $dir/output/ORDER.csv
cat $dir/output/ORDER.del >> $dir/output/ORDER.csv
rm -f $dir/output/ORDER.del
```

I need the file ORDER.csv to be password protected and lets say its 1234 every time.

Comment: See comment about using a password in this question... https://stackoverflow.com/a/16056418/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If zipping is an option for you, then you can password protect the zip file:

```
zip -P 1234 order.zip $dir/output/ORDER.csv
```

Comment: Thank you, how i can achieve the same in gzip ?. I have noticed only gzip is installed in my server

Comment: gzip does not have.. the other option is gpg, but it is a bigger route..

Comment: Thank you, i was able to get zip installed in my server and the above solution is working fine as expected,