# Openssl XChaCha20Poly1305 in Terminal

Tags: openssl, cryptography

**How to use Openssl to encryption and decryption for files by using XChaCha20Poly1305 in Terminal ?**

```
openssl enc -chacha20 -base64 -salt -p -iter 700 -md sha512 -in input.file -out output.file

openssl enc -chacha20 -d -base64 -salt -p -iter 700 -md sha512 -in input.file -out output.file
```

How to implement XChaCha20Poly1305 in this?

Comment: This question is already covered here
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056135/how-to-use-openssl-to-encrypt-decrypt-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056135/how-to-use-openssl-to-encrypt-decrypt-files)

Comment: I need to do XChaCha20Poly1305 algorithm

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.